# apt-get paralyzed by failed dropbox install

Tags: apt, dpkg, dropbox

I tried to install dropbox on my system (Linux Mint 13). `apt-get` proceeded to download the 'dropbox' package. It says it installed it properly, but if I try to run dropbox from the GUI, it does not load. If I try to run it from the command line, it tells me the daemon is not installed and to run `dropbox start -i` to install the daemon. At which point apt-get starts downloading dropbox all over again -- and finally stalls.

All of which is bad enough. But it gets worse. If I try to install anything else using `apt-get`, I am told:

> dpkg was interrupted. Run `sudo dpkg --configure -a` to resolve the problem

and when I run `run dpkg --configure -a`, guess what happens? Yep -- the system starts loading that same friggin' dropbox file again!

A try with `apt-get purge dropbox` produces:

> dpkg was interrupted. Run `sudo dpkg --configure -a` to resolve the problem

Any ideas?

Comment: This is the procedure to fix broken packages - http://blog.bodhizazen.net/linux/apt-get-how-to-fix-very-broken-packages/

Answer (score 1):

This I had already done and in fact someone else had posted a similar problem and after having tried exactly the same thing, received no more answers.

BUT it finally occurred to me-- given that apt-get sends me over to dpkg, why not trying purging there?

sudo dpkg --purge dropbox

and voila'! problem solved!!!

Comment: I can confirm that this works, had exactly the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, first, lets try this:
 - `sudo apt-get --purge remove dropbox`
 - `sudo apt-get install -f`
Try the second thing even if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I read this work-around a few days ago when I was trying to install Dropbox in my Ubuntu 14.04. I followed the following steps:

1. First install dropbox daemon with this command (from the dropbox website):
   `cd ~ && wget -O - "https://www.dropbox.com/download?plat=lnx.x86" | tar xzf -` (for 32-bit systems)
   `cd ~ && wget -O - "https://www.dropbox.com/download?plat=lnx.x86_64" | tar xzf -`(for 64-bit systems)
2. Now Download the .deb file from dropbox website (https://www.dropbox.com/install) and run it. This will install dropbox on your system. Now you can run dropbox directly from dash.